# Matplotlibs: avoid annotations to resize figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have the `tight_layout()` function in matplotlib ignore annotations. As an example, this is a plot with `tight_layout`:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('grey')

ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax2 = plt.subplot(223)
ax3 = plt.subplot(122)

def example_plot(ax, fontsize=12):
     ax.plot([1, 2])
     ax.locator_params(nbins=3)
     ax.set_xlabel('x-label', fontsize=fontsize)
     ax.set_ylabel('y-label', fontsize=fontsize)
     ax.set_title('Title', fontsize=fontsize)

example_plot(ax1)
example_plot(ax2)
example_plot(ax3)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.annotate('a)', xy=(0, 1), xycoords='figure fraction', ha='left', va='top')
plt.annotate('b)', xy=(0, 0.5), xycoords='figure fraction', ha='left', va='top')
plt.annotate('c)', xy=(0.5, 1), xycoords='figure fraction', ha='left', va='top')
```

[image]

[image]

The figure seems to be increased in size (to the left and top) to make space for the annotations (the ylabels don't go all the way to the edge). However, I would like the annotations to be added on top of the figure without any rearrangement. Can I somehow make `tight_layout` ignore these annotations?

---

**Edit:** It is actually not a problem of `tight_layout` it turns out. Even without calling `tight_layout` this resizing of the plot happens:

[image]

[image]

However, if I try the same on a different computer, the expected behavior (no resizing) happens. Both systems run matplotlib 2.0.0 and ipython.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The figure with and without annotations is exactly the same. This is actually clear by even looking at the code, `tight_layout` is called **before** the the annotations are added, so it doesn't even know about them being there or not.

Comment: Your comment made me realize, that `tight_layout` is not the problem. Also without the figure is resized. Confusingly, on another computer with the same version of matplotlib I get the behavior that you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at this from the wrong direction. First of all, there is no "issue". Everything is working as expected.

`tight_layout` does not change the figure size. All it does is rearanging the elements inside the figure, to better use the available space.

What you see is an effect of the saved figure being **cropped** because of the setting `bbox_inches="tight"`. This happens because the `%matplotlib inline` backend shows a saved version of the figure. The image is cut from the original figure such that the saved image contains all elements in the canvas.
The image shown is therefore usually smaller than the original one.

In case however that you put some labels close to the figure edge, the figure cannot be cropped, as this would cut the labels. This may appear as if the figure has grown compared to the case without labels. However, as explained, in reality the figure is just not cropped.

A solution, if needed, is of course to position the labels further away from the figure edge, such that the `bbox_inches="tight"` algorithm can crop more of the figure.

Comment: This clarifies all my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a specific issue if `%matplotlib inline` is used. If I switch to `%matplotlib notebook` instead everything is fine.